# Get a list of eclipse opened projects (Kepler)

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am trying to develop a plugin that will enable special functionality for projects.
I need to get a list of projects currently opened, to further check if my plugin has special settings for these projects.
I have googled that, but all I've got is a reference to org.eclipse.core.resources package. But it seems that Kepler does not have this package anymore (it cannot be added in PDE).
How can I get a list of opened projects names?

Comment: `org.eclipse.core.resources` is still in Kepler. How are you trying to reference it?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake - did not register dependency. Package is in Kepler, thank you.